# User Activity Prediction in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I am struggling with a standard ML problem.
I'm trying to build a service which predicts the next time a user is sending a message on a platform. For this I'm using a historic dataset of the users messages which is structured as an array of timestamps. For example:

```
[2019-05-23 18:28:34.741413, 2019-05-23 18:45:39.643218, 2019-05-23 23:26:44.767524]
```

What is the best way of predicting the next timestamp in this series on when the user will be online?

Currently I am creating a dataframe in Python to then put it into a Sequential() model of keras but I need a y value for doing this.

Thanks for your ideas on how to handle this.

Comment: A good model for the time between two events is the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). However Keras doesn't seem to have a ready-made exponential loss. It's more a statistical problem, than a ML problem.

Answer (score 2):

As a first attempt, I would predict the time duration until the next timestamp. (Regression, not classification.) Probably even better would be to predict the logarithm of that duration instead. Because it is more important to get 2min vs 3min right than to focus on 500min vs 510min.

As inputs you could use the logarithmic time since the last timestamp, and maybe a couple of the previous distances, or logarithm of the last message length, or some general user stats.

But ideally, you'd have the neural network predict the parameters of a probability distribution, such that it can give you an answer like "probably within the next 30 minutes, certainly not after midnight, but possibly after 7am", and then you can measure this prediction against the empirical distribution (e.g. cross-entropy loss). But this is probably a bit too involved for getting started.

If you only want to predict a single timestamp (and not a distribution) then in theory you'd have to define an appropriate loss, and make a decision about which errors are how bad for your application, and then train a model that optimizes this loss.